# How to fix google play services lib r29 problems

Tags: java, android

I'm just reskinning so I don't know too much about Programming , when I want to update my project to google play services lib r29 it gives me errors like: 
[imgur image of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0grL.png)

This lib (google play services lib r29) works with other projects.
Please help me and thanks advance